# How can I see which user is working on what task in Fogbugz?

Tags: fogbugz

I am trying to see which tasks users are working on in FogBugz. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great plugin called FNN by John Fuex that will give you a "FNN - Work In Progress" option in your tools menu (the little briefcase in the top right).

It allows you to see which cases users are working on, along with estimates and other data for that case.

http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/plugins/plugin.aspx?sId=FNN%40improvingsoftware.com

However, if you have the "Performance Upgrade" version of FogBugz On Demand you will not have access to plugins (http://help.fogcreek.com/fogbugz-performance-upgrade/fogbugz-on-demand-plugins).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can't find the plugin menu in my fogbugz. Do I need to have paid version to install plugins? I currently have full feature student version.

Comment: @ozCoder I too use the free Student and Startup edition, so you should be OK. As long as you're logged in as an admin you should see a "Plugins" option when you use the the gear icon from the top right.

Comment: This is the screenshot of my account and the menu, there's no plugin menu. http://gyazo.com/a79f26e94e06c288971c4656205f5398 I am not hosting fogbugz. It's on demand account.

Comment: @ozCoder Turns out if you have the "Performance Upgrade" version of FogBugz On Demand you will not have access to plugins (http://help.fogcreek.com/fogbugz-performance-upgrade/fogbugz-on-demand-plugins).

Comment: Unfortunately it seems so. Thank you very much. The link in the answer works but in the comment is broken because of ')' at the end :)